# why my answer is only partially accepted in a hackerearth practice problem

Tags: c

**Problem**:
You are provided an array A of size  N that contains non-negative integers. Your task is to determine whether the number that is formed by selecting the last digit of all the N numbers is divisible by 10.

Note: View the sample explanation section for more clarification.

Input format

First line: A single integer N denoting the size of array Ai.
Second line: N space-separated integers.
Output format:

If the number is divisible by 10 , then print Yes . Otherwise, print No.

Constraints:
1<=N<=100000
0<=A[i]<=100000

i have used `int`, `long int` ,`long long int` as well for declaring N and 'm'.But the answer was again partially accepted.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long long int N,m,i;
    
    scanf("%ld", &N);
    
    long data[N];
    for(auto i=0; i<N; i++) {
        scanf("%ld", &data[i]);
    }
    
    // write your code here
    // ans = 

    m=(data[0]%10);
    for(i=1; i<N; i++) {
        m=m*10;
        m=(data[i]%10)+m;
    }

    if(m%10!=0 && m==0) {
        printf("Yes");}
    else{
        printf("No");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's probably some corner-case it can't handle correctly. Or invalid input.

Comment: Change `auto i` to `i`, or possibly `int i`.  You will probably never need to use `auto`, and it certainly doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Possibly you need to discover an exact meaning of the verb `formed` in _'the number that is formed by selecting the last digit of all the N numbers'_...?

Comment: @AMRITHA S Show an example of an array and how it is processed to get the result. What does this phrase "the number that is formed by selecting the last digit of all the N numbers" mean?

Comment: This is a strange problem.  All you need to do is look at the last number.  If it ends in zero, the answer is yes.  Otherwise the answer is no.

Comment: The meaining is actually clear,all my sample outputs have passed the test

Comment: The full problem description, plus example, can be found [here](https://code.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/divisible-or-not-81b86ad7/)

Comment: ok an example is if there are 5 inputs;34 70 45 67 80,the number formed by combining the last digits of all numbers is 40570,and the answer is YES since it is divisible by 10.

Comment: @AMRITHA S  This loop for(i=1; i<N; i++){
        m=m*10;
    m=(data[i]%10)+m;
    
} does not make a sense. To determine whether a number is divisible by 10 all you need is to check only that its last digit is equal to 0 provided that the number is not less than 10.

Comment: logically it is correct right?all my sample input and custom inputs passed the test

Comment: If n > 10, your number will overflow and therefore not test correctly against divisibility by 10. As others have noted, the trick is to see that it is enough to test whether the last number is divisible by 10. You don't even need an array.

Comment: https://he-s3.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/cgi-python-fullstack-hiring-challenge/problems/92e9547eb9cf11e9.txt.clean.txt .for this input the test has failed,i dont know why.

Comment: With the large number of input values your calculation will overflow. You only need to check the last digit of the last number, so you don't need to keep all values but the last one. This means you don't need an array to store the values. You could repeatedly read the input into a single variable and check the last value.

Comment: Don't use VLAs if you can't guarantee that the arrays stays small. `ulimit -s` says my stacksize is 8Mb, so for N<=100000 the sizof `data` shouldn't be an issue here. But on other systems the stacksize may be smaller. And if you have other large objects on the stack, this may also make things iffy.

Comment: The last condition `if(m%10!=0 && m==0)` looks strange – if the remainder `m%10` is zero, the first comparison returns false; and when the remainder is non-zero, then `m` certainly is non-zero, too, so the second comparison returns false. As a result, whichever way it goes the whole condition is always false, so the program always prints `"No"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a *test suite*, that is, several tests for which you know the answer. Run your program on each of the tests; compare the result with the correct answer.

When making your tests, try to hit also corner cases. What do I mean by corner cases? You have them in your problem statement:

```
1<=N<=100000
0<=A[i]<=100000
```

- You should have at least one test with minimal and maximal `N` - you should test whether your program works for these extremes.
- You should also have at least one test with minimal and maximal `A[i]`.
- Since each of them can be different, try varying them - make sure your program works on the case where some of the `A[i]` are large and some are small.
- For each category, include tests for which the answer is `Yes` and `No` - to exclude the case where your algorithm always outputs e.g. `Yes` by mistake.

In general, you should try to make tests which challenge your program - try to prove that it has a bug, even if you believe it's correct.

Comment: +1 Very good comment. Creating tests makes us to identify all possible weaknesses of the code, because that's precisely what we try to discover by testing. And finding weaknesses requires identifying all requirements and limitations, both explicit (given in a task) and implicit (imposed by a chosen language, specific compiler or execution environment – eg., a range of `int` type or a maximum size of available memory).

Answer (score 0):

This code overflows:

```
m=(data[0]%10);
    for(i=1; i<N; i++) {
        m=m*10;
        m=(data[i]%10)+m;
    }
```

For example, when `N` is 1000, and each of the input items `A[i]` (scanned into `data[i]`) ends in 9, this attempts to compute `m` = 99999…99999, which grossly overflows the capability of the `long long m`.

To determine whether the numeral formed by concatenating a sequence of digits is divisible by ten, you merely need to know whether the last digit is zero. The number is divisible by ten iff `data[N-1] % 10 == 0`. You do not even need to store these numbers in an array; simply use `scanf` to read but ignore `N`−1 numerals (*e.g.*, `scanf("%*d")`), then read the last one and examine its last digit.

Also `scanf("%ld", &N);` wrongly uses `%ld` for the `long long int N`. It should be `%lld`, or `N` should be `long int`.

Answer (score 0):

An integer number given in decimal is divisible by ten if, and only if, its least significant digit is zero.

If this expression from your problem:

> *the number that is **formed by selecting** the last digit of all the N numbers*

means:

> a number, whose **decimal representation** comes from **concatenating** the least significant digits of all input numbers

then the last (the least significant) digit of your number is the last digit of the last input number. And that digit being zero is equivalent to that last number being divisible by 10.

So all you need to do is read and ignore all input data except the last number, then test the last number for divisibility by 10:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long N, i, data;
    
    scanf("%ld", &N);
    
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        scanf("%ld", &data); // scan all input data

    // the last input number remains in data
    
    if(data % 10 == 0)  // test the last number
        printf("Yes");
    else
        printf("No");


    return 0;
}
```